# Why only dates are returning from a function on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I am using Flask and Pandas to make simple api.But below is main function which is only returning `Dates` from result on heroku.

```
def positions_data(days=3):
    result = {}
    url_dates = result['Dates'] = get_dates(days)

    derivative_dic = defaultdict(dict)

    for date in url_dates:
        df = get_dataframe(date)
#         print(df)
        df = df.applymap(remove_comma)
#         print(df)
        if df.shape[0] != 0:
            extract_fii_data(df,derivative_dic)
        else:
            url_dates.remove(date)

    result['Dates'] = [datetime.strptime(x,'%d%m%Y').strftime('%d-%b-%Y') for x in url_dates]
    result.update(derivative_dic)

    return result
```

`get_dataframe` is making **http request to get csv** file then i use that data and update result and returning it. this is working fine on local host but when I deploy it on heroku it only returning  `Dates` key from result dictionary.

Two functions for getting  data frames

```
def get_dataframe(date:str):
    url = 'https://archives.nseindia.com/content/nsccl/fao_participant_oi_{0}.csv'.format(date)
    print(url)
    csv_data = get_url_data(url)
    csv_col_names = ["Type","FIL","FIS","FSL","FSS","OILC","OILP","OISC","OISP","OSLC","OSLP","OSSC","OSSP","TL","TS"]
    if csv_data != 'NA':
        df  = pd.read_csv(StringIO(csv_data),index_col='Type',skiprows=1,header=0,names=csv_col_names)
    else:
        print("empty data frame")
        df = pd.DataFrame({})
    return df 

def get_url_data(url:str):
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36"}
    data = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    if data.status_code == 200 and data.headers['Content-Type'] == 'text/csv':
        output = data.text 
    else:
        output = "NA"
    return output
```

Comment: What do you mean it only returns `url_dates`? Your function returns `result` which has at least one key `'Dates'` which is a list coming from `url_dates`. Are you saying you only see the `'Dates'` key but no other key? You'd need to log the value of `derivative_dic` to see what's going on. Add some logging so you can debug what happens on heroku.

Comment: @dirkgroten    Sorry for bad explanation. Yes i am only seeing `Dates` key form `result` dictionary .

Comment: The only function that probably modifies `derivative_dic` is `extract_fii_data()` which you're not showing here. If that doesn't modify it, then `derivative_dic` is empty and you won't get other `result` keys. Again, the only way to debug on production is to add logging so you know why `derivative_dic` is empty.

Comment: @dirkgroten    Thanks for logging suggestion. Actually my http request is denied so there is no csv  file and `derivative_dic`is empty. but i  can make multiple requests from locally but on heroku it is getting access denied.

Comment: Then maybe you should show us `get_dataframe` if that’s what’s not working instead of the code you’re showing here.

Comment: @dirkgroten    I added both functions.

Comment: try ssh into your heroku instance and `curl` the url to see if it returns a response that way. But I would advise you to add logging calls in your `get_url_data()` function so you have logs of what happens when fetching the data. Right now just setting `output = "NA"` doesn't help you to figure out what's going on.